# fail2ban | difference between [sshd] in jail.local, vs sshd.local in jail.d?

Tags: ssh, fail2ban

AlmaLinux server -- 1.0.2 fail2ban installed. Seems to be working, but, am hoping someone can clarify something for me:

1\ working with jail.local copy of jail.conf. In said jail.local, there is a Jail section with some code for [sshd].

2\ however, a fair number of 'how to' sites have indicated that I should work with sshd.local in the jail.d subidrectory (already have 00-firewalld.local in said subdir).

So, at present, I have not 'enabled' the [sshd] section in jail.local, but instead (ii) have enabled it in jail.d/sshd.local (configuration shown below -- I use a non-standard port for sshd, which is currently specified in jail.local, although perhaps it could/should be moved to jail.d/sshd.local?)

My question: what is the difference/advantage between setting up [sshd] jail in jail.local, vs creating an sshd.local that gets enabled in jail.d? What puzzles me is that I am currently specify port number in jail.local, but not jail.d/sshd.local -- seems to work, but perhaps I should put all [sshd] jail directives in jail.d/sshd.local?

Thanks...

```
 [sshd]
 enabled = true
 filter = sshd
 logpath = /var/log/secure
 action = iptables-multiport

 # Override the default global configuration
 # for specific jail sshd
 bantime = 4h
 maxretry = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

This comes to the processing order of these configuration files how they override the settings on previously parsed files, as described in [`jail.conf(5)`](https://manpages.debian.org/experimental/fail2ban/jail.conf.5.en.html) man page:

> In addition to `.local`, for `jail.conf` or `fail2ban.conf` file there can be a corresponding `.d/` directory containing additional `.conf` files. The order e.g. for jail configuration would be:
>
> - `jail.conf`
> - `jail.d/*.conf` (in alphabetical order)
> - `jail.local`
> - `jail.d/*.local` (in alphabetical order).
>
> i.e. all .local files are parsed after .conf files in the original configuration file and files under .d directory.  Settings in the file parsed later take precedence over identical entries in previously parsed files.

The purpose of this is to easily distribute the default values while enabling overriding of desired values only.

> `*.conf` files are distributed by Fail2Ban. It is recommended that `*.conf` files should remain unchanged to ease upgrades. If needed, customizations should be provided in `*.local` files. - - In `.local` files specify only the settings you would like to change and the rest of the configuration will then come from the corresponding `.conf` file which is parsed first.

Comment: That is  very helpful.